# Apps freeze when update data in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, freeze

I am able to insert data's into `SQLite` and then populate my `ListView` with the data.

But whenever I try to update the data my phone would freeze and I need to reopen the app to continue

This also occurs on other devices which means there's something in my code which cause the freezing

My Java codes to update the data

```
boolean editContent(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(myDb.COL_NAME, savedName.getText().toString());
    contentValues.put(myDb.COL_IP, savedIP.getText().toString());
    contentValues.put(myDb.COL_PORT, savedPort.getText().toString());
    contentValues.put(myDb.COL_USER_ID, savedUserID.getText().toString());
    contentValues.put(myDb.COL_USER_PASS, savedUserPass.getText().toString());

    //db.update(myDb.TABLE_NAME, contentValues , "ID=" + thisID, null); // problem
    db.update(myDb.TABLE_NAME, contentValues , "ID = '"+ thisID +"'", null);// solution

    if (editContent() == true){
        Toast.makeText(editActivity.this, "Edit Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(editActivity.this, "Edit failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Only logcat I get if I wait awhile is

```
09-09 16:42:14.896 8903-8918/app.my.my W/art: Suspending all threads took: 29.860ms
09-09 16:42:14.922 8903-8924/app.my.my I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 23583(1062KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 125MB/127MB, paused 21.123ms total 75.895ms
09-09 16:42:17.671 8903-8924/app.my.my I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 13051(586KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 126MB/127MB, paused 19.706ms total 84.816ms
09-09 16:42:19.058 8903-8924/app.my.my I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7133(319KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 126MB/127MB, paused 19.733ms total 71.671ms
09-09 16:42:20.202 8903-8924/app.my.my I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3855(171KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 126MB/127MB, paused 20.306ms total 70.792ms
09-09 16:42:20.668 8903-8924/app.my.my I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4903(287KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(37MB) LOS objects, 4% free, 88MB/92MB, paused 20.672ms total 133.448ms
09-09 16:42:31.064 8903-8924/app.my.my I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 48833(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 90MB/92MB, paused 25.972ms total 112.428ms
09-09 16:42:36.098 8903-8924/app.my.my I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 23981(1084KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 91MB/95MB, paused 28.538ms total 150.916ms
09-09 16:42:36.098 8903-8923/app.my.my I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 34.288ms for cause HeapTrim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but most of the time I found the solution to my problem after I post the question on SO

the problem was here

```
db.update(myDb.TABLE_NAME, contentValues , "ID = '"+ thisID +"'", null);// solution

if (editContent() == true){
    Toast.makeText(editActivity.this, "Edit Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}else{
    Toast.makeText(editActivity.this, "Edit failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
```

which I managed to solve by doing this

```
int isUpdated = db.update(myDb.TABLE_NAME, contentValues , "ID = '"+ thisID +"'", null);// solution

if (isUpdated > 0){
    Toast.makeText(editActivity.this, "Edit Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}else{
    Toast.makeText(editActivity.this, "Edit failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
```

it seems the `editContent` `boolean` was the cause for the freezing

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you are creating an infinite loop. i.e. `editContent()` will keep calling `editContent()`, and therefore, never exiting the function. And yes the way you solved it is the right way.